# How to use Jitsi as a softphone SIP client?

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip, client-server, jitsi

Wikipedia lists `Jitsi` features [as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jitsi) including:

`IPv6 support for SIP and XMPP`

But where and how are `SIP` credentials [configured](https://askubuntu.com/q/1273051/847449)?

So that I can [troubleshoot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1273011/847449) an Alice and Bob `SIP` call:

[sip diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ASyN.png)

Above is an image which doesn't seem to be accepted, see also:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/session_initiation_protocol/session_initiation_protocol_basic_call_flow.htm

Comment: Jitsi is mostly synonymous with Jitsi Meet nowadays. You probably want [Jitsi Desktop](https://desktop.jitsi.org/). It is somewhat neglected though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Jigasi. If already installed, take a look at the sample configuration file.

https://github.com/jitsi/jigasi

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks.  I gave you an upvote which doesn't show.  Would elaborate on how `jigasi` is connected to a softphone?

Comment: My apologies, I probably misunderstood the question. Jigasi would act as a SIP UA for Jitsi.

You will need to have a SIP server where Jigasi and the softphone will register with. The SIP server will route calls to Jigasi. You can do this quickly with FreePBX, or with Asterisk if you want to get your hands dirty.